# Eclipse compile progress and error logs as android studio

Tags: eclipse, compilation

Is there have any method to view compile progress and error message as in android studio? thanks!

Comment: There is a small console window usually at the bottom that shows the compilation output. If you do not see it you might have removed it - look in the `view` tab at the top for windows that you unticked.

Comment: By default, in Eclipse Java code is incrementally compiled on save in almost no time. Only initially or when you do _Project > Clean..._ you will see a progress bar in the bottom right corner. Error messages are listed in the _Problems_ view. If you mean not only compiling but building in general, it depends on what you use. For example, when using Gradle, the progress is shown in the _Gradle Executions_ view.